# How to create auto-update date header pattern

Tags: date, ms-word

I'm studying at university, and I have to summarize the lessons every day, how can I create a "date pattren", that will update for today (for example, 01/02), everytime i create a new document?

(when i open the file again in another day i want the date to stay the same, for example, if i will open my "Physics lesson" that i had today another month, i want the header to stay "Physic lesson - 01/**02**" instead of "physic lesson - 01/**03**" (auto update every time i open the file..))

Answer (score 0):

Best would probably be to create a template - .dotx or .dotm if you want macros - and put all the content in there that you want to have every time you create a new document for lesson summary. Use File/New (or double-click) the template to generate a new document from it.

For the date, use a `CREATEDATE` field. This will automatically display the date the document was created and remain static as long as you don't use File/SaveAs. Use field code switches to determine the date format.

You can use Insert/Text/Quick Parts/Field for this. Choose CreateDate from the list on the left. Click in the "Date formats" box at the top of that list (middle of the dialog box) and type: `MM/dd`

Comment: There isn't any more effective way to do that?

Comment: @Nirel The key for your requirement is "auto update every time I open the file". Although on re-reading I think I misunderstood your question - I was for some reason under the impression you'd create a new file every day. I'm going to adjust my answer, but I need to double-check a couple of things: 1) Do you have something against field codes? 2) You do realize that, in order to have Headers with differing content you need SECTION BREAKS in the document? 3) Will/Can this date appear in the content of the document (besides the header)? Because that would let you create "dictionary" headers.